# Can't share Wi-Fi from my Apple silicon Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, vpn, internet-sharing

I wanted to use my MacBook as a VPN hotspot,

I installed Kaspersky VPN on it, then shared it through settings, However, none of my devices can see this new network that I just shared.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I tried this on M2 and M1 Max processors.

Comment: Most likely nothing wrong. There are fundamental issues sharing a VPN client connection via "Internet Sharing". Unless Kaspersky explicitly supports what you want, I would not expect it to work. Maybe you have a reference to where Kaspersky support talk about what you want.

Comment: Yes, but eithernet to wifi doesn't work either, seems like a macOS bug.

Comment: To expand on Gilby's comment: my experience is that VPN clients block Internet Sharing, for example, the VPN client we use at work (Cisco AnyConnect) doesn't support VPN sharing. You say Ethernet to Wi-Fi doesn't work either, I've tested sharing my Ethernet connection over Wi-Fi and can confirm that it works on Monterey, could it be that Kaspersky VPN is interfering?

Comment: @jaume I've tested on m1 max and m2 processors, maybe you are testing on an intel mac and that's why it works for you

Comment: Yes, that's right, I've tested Internet Sharing on an Intel Mac, but I think that's not relevant... which macOS version are you on?

Comment: @jaume the latest version. How is it not relevant? It's new hardware, which potentially hasn't been tested properly. And it doesn't work on 2 laptops. one laptop running m2 and the other one running m1 max.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I understand you could reproduce the issue with two different Apple Silicon Macs, so the processor architecture _could_ be relevant, but honestly, I can't imagine that's the cause. I mean, Internet Sharing isn't some obscure functionality... If that were indeed an issue, I'd expect Apple would've fixed it pretty quickly, but that's just my opinion, and you may be right. It would be great if someone who owns an Apple Silicon Mac could test it and post the results.

Comment: @jaume how do you know that they didn't upgrade the wifi module along with updating processors? Maybe the old one was compatible only with intel and they changed it too. I read it somewhere that apple silicon macs are the first macs to support wifi 6, for example, so I think they definitely changed something.